Numbered lists with lines beginning with numbers look odd in Safari
This question contains the following passage:

Chess.com tells me that



a4 is the last book move;




... c5 is an inaccuracy.




It looks good in most browsers, but in Safari, both on macOS 15.2 (Safari 18.2) and on iOS 18.2, the 'move number' (17.) overlaps with the row number:


This is what it should look like (and probably does for most users - this is Firefox):

Looking at the HTML, I see that the Markdown converter renders this as nested lists. I'm not sure if that is according to spec, or that the CSS needs some tweaking here.

Well to be fair the markdown can't know the 17. isn't meant as additional list, hence it's correctly nesting it. (i.e. that part isn't a bug.)
